# Get remote .js to work

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a tiny piece of script. It's working when I add it directly into my page. But how do I make it working when the script is in a .js file? And is it enough to put the code into a .js file? Or do I need to add extra lines of code?

I know I have to refer to the file in the header. But that doesn't do the trick. This is the script:

```
    $("#david").mouseover(function() {
    $('#charlotte').addClass('hover');
    $('#timon').addClass('hover');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#charlotte').removeClass('hover');
    $('#timon').removeClass('hover');    

});

$("#charlotte").mouseover(function() {
    $('#david').addClass('hovert');
    $('#timon').addClass('hovert');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#david').removeClass('hovert');
    $('#timon').removeClass('hovert');    

});

$("#timon").mouseover(function() {
    $('#david').addClass('hovertt');
    $('#charlotte').addClass('hovertt');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#david').removeClass('hovertt');
    $('#charlotte').removeClass('hovertt');    

});
```

I hope you guys can help me out!

I know it's a very basic question, but I can't find the answer I need and I'm still a noob at making scripts..

Comment: have you included the jquery library before including your external script?

Comment: like <script src="jquery.js"></script><script src="yourscript.js"></script>

Comment: Ok. And I don't have to refer to the .js file in the html file, but only in the header?

Comment: what do you mean only in the header? the header is inside your html file only..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to include that javascript file in your html page:

```
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="pathToYourScript/yourscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

furthenrmore you will need to tell the js when to execute and I would recomend either  wrapping your code in

```
$(document).ready(function{
 // your code here 
})
```

or in window.load

```
$(window).load(function{
 // your code here 
})
```

or in self executing function :

```
(function(){
 // your code here 
})();
```

Comment: Ok. But I don't need to call any code in the html... All the functions are in de .js file...

Comment: Exactly, just move the js code in your.js  file. Wrap it in window.load or doc.ready like i explained above (to make sure it will be executed at the right time). Then include the script in your html header  with the <script> tag

Comment: @user1737979, without calling anything from the html file will not do anything in the output..

Answer (score 0):

Within the your HTML document add the second line after your jQuery script.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/name-of-your-file.js"></script>
```

In the example, I've prepended `/js/` to your scripts. It's best practice to separate your files into specific folders, so you'll have to create a new `js` folder. Also, jQuery needs to be in place and ready for you to start using it. If you need to wait for the document to load then you'll need to wrap your code in the following.

```
$(function() {
  // Past your code here.
  // This syntax is simply a shortcut for 
  // $(document).ready(function(){});
});
```